# What is the normal 'Line of code' to 'Unit test code' ratio for C language?

Tags: c

The source code is developed in C language and is developed for Linux platform. I want to develop unit test program in C language  for getting 100% code coverage.

What is the normal  'Line of code' to 'Unit test code' ratio for C language? We are expecting 750 LOC unit test program for 1000 LOC source.

Is this considered a normal value?

Comment: How are we supposed to give an objective answer to such a subjective question?

Answer (score 1):

First off, remember that 100% code coverage does not really tell that much how many of the possible failure cases are covered by the tests.

Amount of test code varies a lot:

- Some fairly successful projects have close to 0% of test code.
- Some projects such as [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) have 81100% of test code.
- Some readings from my own projects that I consider "reasonably well tested, but definitely still have bugs": 189%, 78%.

Really, it depends on the projects and usually you'll want other kinds of tests than just unit testing also. For example fuzz testing is quite useful even for non-security critical code and mandatory for anything that gets exposed to untrusted data.